# Handle Arbitrary Exception, Print Default Exception Message

Tags: python, exception

I have a program, a part of which executes a loop. During the execution of this loop, there are exceptions. Obviously, I would like my program to run without errors, but for the sake of progress, I would like the program to execute over the entire input and not stop when an exception is thrown. The easiest way to do this would be by implementing an `except` block.

However, when I do this, it `except`s all exceptions and continues with the program and I never get to see the exception message, which I need in order to debug.

Is there a way to `except` any arbitrary exception and be able to print out the exception message in the `except` block?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
try:
    #stuff
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

The `traceback` module provides various functions for extracting more information from the exception object (`e`, above).

Source [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Note that the `Exception, e` syntax is deprecated as of 2.6, and stops working as of 3.0. If you have code that has to work with both 2.x and 3.x, use `Exception as e` instead. (However, if you need to work with 2.5 or earlier, you have to use this syntax.)

Answer (score 12):

Consider using the Python logging module, this is will give you a lot of the functionality to log problems for later inspection. Below is a simple example of using the logging module to to log exceptions:

```
import logging
LOG_FILE = '/tmp/exceptions.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILE,level=logging.ERROR)

while True:
try:
    # Code that may throw exceptions
except Exception, e:
    logging.exception("An exception happened")
```

By using the `logging.exception` function within an exception handler as is done here the Exception info is automatically added to the logging message.

Answer (score 9):

While James's answer is almost always what you actually want, it's not quite what the OP asked for:

> Is there a way to except any arbitrary exception and be able to print out the exception message in the except block?

[`Exception`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception) doesn't actually handle *all* exceptions, just all exceptions you usually want to catch. In particular, in 2.5 and later:

> All built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions are derived from this class. All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class.

This leaves out a few things:

- built-in system-exiting exceptions, like a [`KeyboardInterrupt`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) from the user hitting `^C` (2.5 and later only)
- user-defined exceptions that don't follow that "should"

Very occasionally, you want to handle things like `KeyboardInterrupt`, in which case you use [`BaseException`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException) instead of `Exception`. (See [Exception hierarchy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) for a list of which exceptions are and are not `Exception` subclasses.) So:

```
try:
    # stuff
except BaseException as e:
    print e
```

And (usually temporarily while debugging) sometimes you really do want to handle absolutely everything. In 2.7, that includes exceptions defined as old-style classes; in 2.5 and earlier, it also includes strings. The only way to handle all of those possibilities is to use a bare `except` and then use [`sys.exc_info`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) (and, optionally, re-`raise` anything you didn't want to handle):

```
try:
    # stuff
except:
    type, value, traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print value
```

As a side note, I'm using the new-style `except` syntax (`except Exception as e`) above. This works in 2.6 and later, including 3.x. The old-style syntax (`except Exception, e`) is deprecated in 2.6, and stops working in 3.0, but if you want to work with older 2.x versions you need to use it.

Answer (score 5):

I find this to be much more useful for debugging:

```
from traceback import print_exc
try:
    raise Exception("doh!")
except:
    print_exc()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
while True:
    try:
        # Do your stuff
    except Exception, e:
        print "Something happened: %s" % e
```

Comment: In python 3 use instead `print("Something happened: {}".format(e))`.