# Print Python Exception Type (Raised in Fabric)

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I'm using Fabric to automate, including the task of creating a directory. Here is my fabfile.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from fabric.api import *

def init():
    try:
        local('mkdir ./www')
    except ##what exception?##:
        #print exception name to put in above
```

Run fab `fabfile.py` and f I already have `./www` created an error is raised, but I don't know what kind, so I don't know how to handle the error yet. Fabric only prints out the following:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘./www’: File exists

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'mkdir ./www'

Aborting.
```

What I want to do is be able to find out the error type so that I can except my errors properly without blanket statements. It would be really helpful if an answer does not just tell me how to handle a `mkdir` exception, but print (or otherwise find the name to) *any* exception I may run into down the line (mkdir is just an example).

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle Arbitrary Exception, Print Default Exception Message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005680/handle-arbitrary-exception-print-default-exception-message)

Comment: I attempted with those, but it does not work as I am running the code through Fabric, thus your suggestion doesn't work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that fabric uses subprocess for doing these sorts of things.  If you look at the source code for `local` you can see it doesn't actually raise an exception.  It calls suprocess.Popen and uses `communicate()` to read stdout and stderr.  If there is a non-zero return code then it returns a call to either `warn` or `abort`.  The default is abort.  So, to do what you want, try this:

```
def init():
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        local('mkdir ./www')
```

If you look at the source for `abort`, it looks like this:

```
 10 def abort(msg):
 21     from fabric.state import output
 22     if output.aborts:
 23         sys.stderr.write("\nFatal error: %s\n" % str(msg))
 24         sys.stderr.write("\nAborting.\n")
 25     sys.exit(1)
```

So, the exception would be a SystemExit exception.  While you could catch this, the proper way to do it is outlined above using `settings`.

Comment: If it saves someone else a google search: from fabric.api import settings

Answer (score 3):

It is nothing to handle with exception, it is from the fabric api

try to set the entire script's warn_only setting to be true with

```
  env.warn_only = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you get an uncaught exception, Python will print the exception type along with the error message:

```
>>> raise IOError("Error message.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: Error message.
```

If that's not happening, you're probably not getting an exception at all.

If you really want to catch an arbitrary exception and print it, you want to catch `Exception` or `BaseException`. `BaseException` will include even things like `KeyboardInterrupt`, though, so be careful with that.

```
def init():
try:
    local('mkdir ./www')
except BaseException as e:
    print "local() threw a", type(e).__name__
    raise # Reraise the exception
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def init():
    try:
        local('mkdir ./www')
    except Exception as e:
        print e.__class__.__name__
```

That's all there is to it!

edit: Just re-read your question and realized that my code would only print "Fatal" in your case. It looks like fabric is throwing an error and returning their own error code so you would have to look at the documentation. I don't have any experience with fabric so I'd suggest to look [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/execution.html#failures) if you haven't already. Sorry if this isn't helpful!

Answer (score -1):

In general:

```
    try:
        some_code()
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Hit An Exception', e
        raise
```

Will tell you what the exception was but if you are not planning on actually handling *some of* the exceptions then simply getting rid of the try: except: lines will have exactly the same effect.

Also if you run your code under a debugger then you can look at the exception(s) that you hit in more detail.